# Are there any critiques on the Self-Determination Theory by Deci & Ryan?

Tags: motivation, self

I am currently reading about the self-determination-theory (SDT) and tried to find an article dealing with the disadvantages of this theory. However i couldn't find anything. Does anybody know some disadvantages/ articles etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The University of Zurich has [a pdf file of an article](https://www.uzh.ch/iou/orga/ssl-dir/wiki/uploads/Main/Controversy.pdf) which was directly from the University of Rochester School of Arts and Sciences.

The article has an outline of many criticisms of SDT from behaviourists such as Eisenberger, Cameron and Pierce, which were later discounted as invalid.

References to all relevant articles are within the pdf file.

Comment: The link that Chris Rogers posted is now dead. Does anyone know the title of the article?

Comment: That is annoying @kylegroger  I will try and find it again.  I can't remember it's title.